How to use Pigeon in Flutter to communicate with C++ code on Windows platform?
I am trying to utilize Pigeon within Flutter to establish communication with C++ code on the Windows platform. While there are ample examples online for communication with Android and iOS, I haven't found any regarding Windows interaction. Following examples related to Android and iOS, I have successfully implemented communication with Kotlin. However, I haven't come across examples for Windows interaction. The official documentation for Pigeon seems to focus on writing plugins rather than apps. I have generated code according to Pigeon's documentation and written C++ implementation. However, I am unsure of how to compile the code, especially modifying the CMakeLists.txt, and successfully run the Windows program. Can someone provide a simple yet comprehensive example, such as calling the C++ add() function and displaying the result on the screen?
I have followed the Pigeon documentation to generate code and written the C++ implementation. However, I am struggling with compiling the code, particularly modifying the CMakeLists.txt, and running the Windows program successfully. I expected to find examples or documentation specifically addressing Windows platform interaction using Pigeon, but I haven't found any so far.

First, always develop native code in a plugin project. Eventually, depend your main project on the native one. While developing, use the example app that comes with the plugin to test. Second, note that pigeon uses traditional method channels, for which the native language in Windows is C++. This is not the same as Dart FFI, for which the add is the classic example. So, get yourself a working plugin, which should just compile out of the box and show you the default example of OS version. Then modify that code.

At that point it will be obvious how to follow the pigeon instructions about Add the generated C++ code to your ./windows directory for compilation, and to your windows/CMakeLists.txt file.

@Richard Heap Thank you. When I begin to develop plugin, I found it is much easier to understand the examples provided by pigeon.
